# Coloring section title without redefining the numbering

Tags: color

On [this testing document](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/58e4e28a54b8ca05149425b0) I am showing the issue I have run into. I am trying to make a background color for all section titles, but with the method I use I redefine the numbering resulting in both `\section{...}` **and** `\section*{...}` becoming numbered:

[image]

I of course don't want sections with the star * to become numbered as well. Can I make an edit to the fairly short code I am using to solve this? Below is a the latex code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec} % Title manipulation

\titleformat{\section}          % Background on sections
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\colorbox{red}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\textcolor{black}{\thesection\quad#1}}}}

\begin{document}
\section*{Section title unnumbered}
\section{Section title numbered}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to code two  format, using the numberless key for one:

```
\titleformat{\section}          % Background on sections
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\colorbox{red}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\textcolor{black}{\thesection\quad#1}}}}

\titleformat{name=\section, numberless}          % Background on sections
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\colorbox{red}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\textcolor{black}{#1}}}}
```